# MySQL using index condition

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two tables with structure that can be described as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `sub_schedule` (
  `ScheduleID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ServiceID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `RunTime` time NOT NULL,
  `Status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  `Telco` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ScheduleID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `mt` (
  `MtID` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ServiceID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Moperator` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Cmd` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CreateDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`MtID`),
  KEY `CreateDate` (`CreateDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Mt table is big one and the sub_schedule table is holding less then 500 records.

When i try to run this query:

```sql
EXPLAIN 
 SELECT m.serviceid
      , m.createdate
      , m.moperator
   FROM mt m
   JOIN sub_schedule ss 
     ON m.serviceid = ss.serviceid 
    AND ss.status = "A" 
    AND ss.telco LIKE CONCAT('%', m.moperator, '%')
  WHERE m.createdate >= addtime((subdate(curdate(), 1)),ss.runtime) 
    AND m.createdate <= addtime((subdate(curdate(), 0)),ss.runtime)
    AND m.cmd LIKE "SUBS%";
```

It produce this output:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key  , key_len, ref  , rows     , Extra
 1, SIMPLE     , ss   , ALL , NULL         , NULL , NULL   , NULL ,      470 , Using where
 1, SIMPLE     , m    , ALL , CreateDate   , NULL , NULL   , NULL , 57610462 , Range checked for each record (index map: 0x10)
```

It seems that it doesn't use index for `createdate` in that query which result in very long query execution time. Already tried with `FORCE INDEX` and different approaches to that query and tried to move `createdate` to the `ON` condition part and use `FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN`. 
So my question is: Is there any way to make mysql actually use index for `createdate` field?

Comment: Can you post which are the indexes you created.?

Answer (score 0):

There is no index on `mt.serviceid` therefore all rows from `mt` must be scanned to fulfill the condition `m.serviceid = ss.serviceid`. Other conditions on this table can and will be checked during the full table scan.

Add an index on `mt(serviceid, createdate)` or `mt(createdate, serviceid)` (not sure which one will yield best results).

*Note: if you decide to go with and index on `mt(createdate, serviceid)`, then the index on `mt(createdate)` [becomes superfluous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5022947/1446005).*

Comment: thanks for the reply. i added the `serviceid` index to mt table but it stills scan every record

Comment: How many rows does the query return? How many without the `WHERE` clause? When the query returns most rows, the optimizer may decide not to use an index. Also, please make sure you created a **composite index** on `serviceid` **and** `createdate` (not just `serviceid`).

Comment: Nah, even if the index is on `serviceid `only, this index could be used on the JOIN condition. I suppose your query just returns most rows from the table.

Comment: I need to double check it. Could provide more clear result tomorrow. Thanks for the help.